# How to get Auth code from Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication

I have integrated Facebook sdk into my project to give Facebook authentication. Once user successfully logged In, i need to send auth code to the server. Server will return access token Id against auth code.

Is there any way to  get auth code from Facebook sdk?

Please help me.

Comment: With the mobile SDKs, you get an access token directly, not a code.

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks, That's true but I want auth code. Do have any idea  about any third party api help me to get auth code?

Comment: Why do you want the code? // You can of course implement the manual login flow, then you have full control over what happens. But then it won’t be the “native” Android login any more, but will happen in a webview.

Answer (score -2):

When facebook return value you can handle data in

```
@Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Log.e("FB token", accessToken.getToken());
        Log.e("User Id", accessToken.getUserId());
        //can check auth code here
        if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
            profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                    Log.e("Profile Changed", newProfile.getName());
                    profileTracker.stopTracking();
                }
            };
        } else {
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where is the answer of my question? I don't want token, i want auth code. Please read question first.

Comment: when you are using facebook SDK in android you cannot directly get auth code, you can only check access token only.

Comment: Thanks, I have to think much more

Comment: The question was about auth code, not auth token, kindly look into how facebook handles implicit auth flow before posting an answwer here.
Also, @RohanPatel if you found an answer you can post it here to help other.

Comment: Looks like the javascript SDK has a "signedRequest" field that can be decoded on the server which has an auth code, but I can't find anything like this for android or ios sdk's.